# trying to add background color via javascript to html element

Tags: javascript, html

so I have an array, containing titles and covers for movies. I'm trying to display the names in the flexbox, using cover image as background image.
I also tried to write it like that: `document.div.style.backgroundColor = "url(infoForThatDay[each]['cover'])";` but it didn't work either

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
for(let each in moviesToDisplay) {
    let div = document.createElement("div")
    div.innerText = moviesToDisplay[each]['title'];
    
    //That is where I'm trying to set the background color
    div.style.backgroundColor = "url(moviesToDisplay[each]['cover'])";
    flex.appendChild(div);
}
```

Thank you in advance <3
have a great day ^_^

Comment: Remove the quotes around `"url(infoForThatDay[each]['cover'])"` so that the expression is evaluated and not used literally as the background color.

Comment: This is incorrect @ScottMarcus, you still need `url()` if it's an image value.

Comment: @bryce Yes, but you don't want quotes around the dynamic portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.style.background = `url("${moviesToDisplay[each]['cover']}")`;
```

To set image as background, either set `backgroundImage` or `background` property.

Also, you will need to use string interpolation else it will set the background image to whatever the string is.

Also, `url()` takes a string, that's why `""` are required.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use string interpolation to get the value. You also can't use `url` values with `background-color`, you should use `background` instead:

```js
div.style.background = `url(${moviesToDisplay[each]['cover']})`;
```

Comment: thanks so much, i figured i needed to use ``-s but i couldn't figure out where <3